# Unable to use elements in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I can not interact with `WebElement`s using xpath or ID. On our login page it works fine but next I get NoSuchElement exception e.g. I want to interact with text input which is located in Search dialogue.

[image: Page Screenshot]

DOM for this element looks like this: [image: DOM screenshot]

I tried to use xpath expressions:

1. `.//input[contains(@id, 'frmMain_ctrlSearchString')][1]`
2. `.//input[contains(@id, 'frmMain_ctrlSearchString')][2]`
3. `.//span[contains(@id, 'frmMain_ctrlSearchString')][1]`
4. `.//span[contains(@id, 'frmMain_ctrlSearchString')][2]`
5. Also used some full ID's using `By.Id expression`

WebDriver's `switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys();` works well

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a wait issue to me

After Login-in it tries to look for elements on the next page but as the page is not loaded you are getting **NoSuchElement Exception**. In order to solve this you need to add a wait

Here is an example on how and when to use [wait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27619664/4855423) when interacting with UI Element

Comment: i'm using driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: Can you add HTML snippet, your code and which line it's failing on

Comment: here is my element:     @Name("Search textbox")
    @FindBy(xpath = ".//input[contains(@id, 'frmMain_ctrlSearchString')][1]")
    private TextInput SearchTextbox;   // trying to interact with using senkeys("");

Comment: i cannot add html snippet here because of number of symbols. How can i contact you?

Comment: I see 2 input tag in the screen shot did you try locating other one instead.
I cannot help without knowing the stack trace

Comment: @Akshar, yes i tried. I cannot upload all the information here

Comment: @artkoshelev, @Name("MSW Elements")
@FindBy(xpath = "//form[@class='page_form']")

Comment: i'cant see this element in your DOM hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Did you test xpath you use in browser? There are lots of plugins for Firefox, one of them is [XPather](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpather/).

Comment: Of course. I'm using firepath. You see the second pic with DOM, it higlights needed element. Moreover i tried to find by id

Answer (score 0):

Try / check:

1. wait for longer time
2. check if it is in some frame (must switch in)
3. check right xpath or identifier, if there is not another element before in DOM with suitable identifier

Comment: 1. Implicity is set to 15 sec; 2. i see no frame tags in DOM; 3. firepath highlits only 1 element in DOM. Looks like another layer which prevents interacting with